# Insert mysql row only if all other rows in that table have a value of 0

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert a mysql entry only if all other rows have state=0 in that table.

eg. There are 350 tournament rows in the tournament table all with state=0 and 1 row with state=2. When the query runs I want it to check that only one row exists with state=2 and if it does then perform the insert, if not don't.

I tried this as a solution but it fails:

```
INSERT INTO newTournaments(`start`,`registration`,`end`,`prize`,`state`) 
VALUES('1','1','1','1','1') 
where (SELECT id FROM newTournaments WHERE state != 0) = tournamentId;
```

Comment: For future reference, it also helps if you show us what results and/or errors you are getting from your query.

Comment: @Tom Starkie, either "I am trying to insert a mysql entry only if all other rows have state=0 in that table." OR "When the query runs I want it to check that only one row exists with state=2 and if it does then perform the insert, if not don't." ?

Comment: Your insert statement fails BTW because INSERT statement cannot have a WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems the case where insert via select statement will help:

```
INSERT INTO newTournaments(`start`,`registration`,`end`,`prize`,`state`) 
SELECT '1','1','1','1','1'
FROM (select 'a') a
WHERE (SELECT count(*) FROM newTournaments WHERE state = 2) = 1
```

**[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/65e61)**

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you very much.

Comment: @TomStarkie, I did an update so that one and only one row is inserted (of course, if the condition in the where clause is validated).